# Ansible json_query outputs list when using a filter expression

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I'm running ansible 2.4.0 on OSX.
The following playbook...

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    data:
    - name: thing1
      desc: I am thing 1
    - name: thing2
      desc: I am thing 2

  tasks:
  - debug: msg="{{ data|json_query(\"[1].desc\") }}"
  - debug: msg="{{ data|json_query(\"[?name=='thing2'].desc\") }}"
```

Produces the following output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I am thing 2"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "I am thing 2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

My question is, why, in the second debug task is the output in a list ([])?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because in JMESPath, which is the [implementation behind `json_query`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/0b29162b9783579de976ca349db18376ed59e5b5/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/json_query.py), an index expression is defined to always return a single value, possibly `null` ([see [1]](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#indexexpressions)).

While for the filter expression, which is a projection, an array is assumed to be returned after evaluating the LHS of your query, which may be empty in case no values are matched ([see: [2]](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections)).

Answer (score 4):

You can add ansible filter `first`, like so:

```
tasks:
  - debug: msg="{{ data | json_query(\"[?name=='thing2'].desc\") | first }}"
```

It'll return scalar value.